# Ckfinder showing page not found?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I am using ckeditor module and for file browser I selected the ckfinder module. When I click on browser server ti shows the page not found in ckfinder popup.

I have checked the permissions and matched the config.php with other site. When I check the browser console, I found the below issue :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>   http://example.com/sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=Init&type=Images&id=Full

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/713724 = CKFinder "Browse Server" = Page not found

Comment: I already looked at the post but it didn't solved my problem.

Comment: Well, there count of instructions on comments below, one of these should help...

Comment: I tried all but :(

Comment: well, I can check it only on-place...